# Writing to the datastore without closing Persistence Manager

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, persistence-manager

How to commit to the database when updating an object using PersistenceManager without closing it?

Comment: why not show the code of what you are currently doing, in particular, where is your transaction (assuming you have one)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit the transaction. You don't need to close the PersistenceManager.

```
PersistenceManager p;
...
p.currentTransaction().begin();
.... //do the work
p.currentTransaction().commit();
```